# Extracting street space polygons from a pedestrian network with separate sidewalk geometries using QGIS/PyQGIS

Tags: qgis, openstreetmap, routing, network

I have a network of sidewalk geometries including crossings extracted from [OpenStreetMap](https://www.openstreetmap.org/#map=14/52.4742/13.4208) (OSM; here: a part of Neukölln district in Berlin, Germany) using [overpass turbo](https://overpass-turbo.eu/s/1CaQ) (as of today, some gaps still need to be closed).

I want to work with this data in QGIS. In a next step, I extract the street space network using using the "Polygonize" processing tool. Then I extract all Polygons that touch roadways by adding the respective layer, also extracted from OSM, using the "Extract by location" tool in QGIS. The result looks already quite nice for a large part of the area, see screenshot (background map © OpenStreetMap contributors).

[image]

However, it is obvious that a solution for dead ends not enclosed by sidewalk geometries is still missing. I have not found a solution here yet, as also some buffering options did not lead to a satisfying result. I am looking for a solution to solve this using the QGIS GUI.

Any hints that point me to the right direction are welcome. If you think that this is not possible using the GUI without additional Python coding, please also let me know.

Comment: Perhaps a convex hull would be better if your data extract areas are mostly rectangular or circular (not C shaped) https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/283111/creating-minimum-convex-polygon-around-points-in-qgis though if available OpenStreetMap may have property boundaries https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/89236/does-openstreetmap-have-property-boundaries, or you might have to source them elsewhere... using the sidewalks select the land parcels then close islands with polygonize and use the result for your selection.

Comment: Please decide whether you wish to ask about doing this in the QGIS GUI, using PyQGIS or using another Python library.  If it's one of the latter two, then please include a code attempt.